# Connected Subgroups of $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

> Question:
>   What are the connected subgroups of $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$?

Connected Lie subgroups of $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ are in 1:1-correspondence with Lie subalgebras of $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{R})$.
If we denote the usual root decomposition of $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{R})$ by

$$
\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{R})
=
\mathfrak{g}_0 \oplus \mathfrak{g}_\alpha \oplus \mathfrak{g}_{-\alpha},
$$

then we clearly have the following Lie subalgebras:
$\{0\},
\mathfrak{g}_0,
\mathfrak{g}_\alpha,
\mathfrak{g}_{-\alpha},
\mathfrak{so}(2),
\mathfrak{g}_0 \oplus \mathfrak{g}_\alpha,
\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{R})$
and all conjugates of those, e.g. $Ad(g)(\mathfrak{g}_\alpha)$ for $g \in SL(2, \mathbb{R})$.

But I have a hard time imagining what other groups are there.

Background:
I want to know all subgroups of the isometry group of $Isom(\mathbb{RH}^2 \times \mathbb{RH}^2)=SL(2,\mathbb{R}) \times SL(2,\mathbb{R})$.
That classification will follow with Goursat's lemma from the answer to my question.

Comment: See the references [here](https://www.eweb.unex.es/eweb/extracta/Vol-27-2/27B2Thompson.pdf).

Comment: Using the root decomposition is not the right approach. The way to do (by oneself, which is better that reading a reference): classify 1-dimensional ones, then 2-dimensional ones. 2-dimensional Lie algebras are either either abelian, or their derived subgroup is 1-dimensional. To classify the nonabelian ones in $sl_2$ one has to compute the normalizer of the 1-dimensional subalgebras.

Comment: @YCor Thanks. Any suggestion how to check if two subalgebras are conjugate? That's already difficult for me to do for the 1-dimensional subalgebras, let alone the 2-dimensional ones.

Comment: Hint: for a element, the unordered pair of eigenvalues is a conjugacy invariant. Hence, for a 1-dimensional subalgebra, the unordered pair of eigenvalues, up to scalar multiplication, is a conjugacy invariant.

Comment: @YCor Okay, this tells me which subalgebras are conjugate by an element in $GL(2,\mathbb{R})$. The other ingredient that I needed was "If two invertible matrices are conjugate by a matrix with negative determinant, then they are not conjugate by a matrix with positive determinant". I am left to check by hand which singular matrices in $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{R})$ are conjugate. The only subalgebras of singular matrices are $\mathfrak{g}_\alpha$ and $\mathfrak{g}_{-\alpha}$ and they are not conjugate by a matrix in $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$, as direct calculation shows. Thanks.

Comment: They're conjugate by the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}0 & -1\\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ which is in $\mathrm{SL}_2$.

Comment: In yoccoz article about SL(2,R),there is a theorem about conjugacy of  bounded sequence of these matrices which got from cocycles.you can check that maybe works for you.but i think first you should know the classification of SL(2,R) and then each class has its own classes which is in "BMS Particles
in Three Dimensions from Oblak".